# Why does visual studio replace my version of MVC with version 5.2.3 when adding a partial?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added a partial via the right click menu option `MVC 5 Partial Page (Razor)` (current MVC version 5.1) and visual studio automatically upgraded my packages to `MVC 5.2.3`, `web pages 3.2.3` and `web infrastructure 1.0.0.0`.

I spotted the changes before committing and discarded them.  But they come back every time I use the menu option.  The change is incompatible with my app.

The app throws an error with the change references, so this is a breaking change for me.
The incompatibility could be due to the CMS we use which is Sitecore.

> Error produced is Method not found: 'Void
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory..ctor(System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory)'.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using specifically.  Also, to test, I would create a blank new project and try to add a view and see if you get the same error.  That could tell you if it's visual studio or something in the project like the CMS you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Using visual studio version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL. I will update it and see if the problem disappears. I added another partial to a different project (basic MVC project) and it did not update the references but it tried to:Attempting to install version '3.2.3' of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor' but the project already includes a different version. Skipping...
Attempting to install version '3.2.3' of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages' but

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your web.config settings for the max value (here 5.2.2.0):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Currently: 
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                          xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />